# BSOD after installing HyperX Fury SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bsod

I bought this [Kingston HyperX FURY 120GB SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KW3MTBS), I installed it on my PC (specs below) and went for a fresh Windows 7 Ultimate x64 install on my SSD. The installation process was succesfull, everything seemed perfect. I started installing my drivers and main software that I'm using. A few hours later, I got a BSOD while doing quite nothing (viewing some images using Firefox). I suspect that the cause is the SSD I just installed, as I haven't had a bluescreen since my last damaged HDD (this one is great). [Here](http://pastebin.com/bYKQ5YZK) is the (output of the) dump file that windows generated. I posted the actual dmp file in the comments below.
What could be wrong? What can I do from now on?

```
Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2200 @ 2.20GHz
MB: G31TM-P35 (MS-7529)
RAM: 2GB DDR2 800MHz
HDD: 500GB WDC WD5000AAKX-00ERMA0 ATA
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS 512MB
Sound Card: Envy24 Family Audio Controller WDM
Optical drive: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22NS50 ATA
SSD: the one I mentioned
```

Thank you!

Edit: 2 days later and there hasn't been any problem, should I be worried or just ignore the BSOD and hope it never happens again?

Comment: Post the full dump file (not the text output), maybe someone here will debug it.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Do you want me to upload the dump file on a host and then post the link here?

Comment: Yes, there are some members here that will debug it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SATA cable between the motherboard and the SSD may have been loose. It probably will be fine from now on as long as it isn't severely bent or stretched so far that it is barely keeping connection.